# Can Echo dot do Open Sound Control

Tags: osc

I wanna develop an Alexa Skill to communicate with my devices using Open Sound Control through Local Area Network.

After little research it seems that the Echo dot do not allow us to programme it to connect with local devices. Is there any work around without the need of a Raspberry Pi as a middle man?